# Paginating with field value that occurs multiple times returns same documents every time firestore

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, nosql

I have a query for comments with a orderBy field of threadCommentCount. A lot of comments will have a threadCommentCount of 0 so everytime I pass in the last comment threadCommentCount into another query with a startAfter value of 0, it returns the same set of data everytime. How would I fix this? Can I add another startAfter or orderBy after the first one to order by timePosted or something? Here is the cloud function I'm using. This only happens for when the orderBy query value is 'popular', recent works perfectly.

```
const postId = req.query.postId;
    const userHandle = req.user.userHandle;
    const orderBy = req.query.orderBy;
    const startAfter = req.query.startAfter;

    db
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(postId)
        .get()
        .then(async (doc) => {
            if(!doc.exists){
                throw 'postNotFound';
            }
            else {
                    let popularCommentsQuery;
                    popularCommentsQuery = db
                        .collection('comments')
                        .where('postId', '==', postId)
                        .orderBy('threadCommentCount', 'desc')
                        .startAfter(startAfter)
                        .limit(15) // this is the query that I'm having problems with
                    const popularComments = await popularCommentsQuery.get();
                    return popularComments;
            }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            const promises = data.map((doc) => {
                return {
                    userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
                    comment: doc.data().comment,
                    commentId: doc.id,
                    postId: doc.data().postId,
                    threadCommentCount: doc.data().threadCommentCount,
                    commentedAt: doc.data().commentedAt
                };
            });
            Promise.all(promises)
            .then((comments) => {
                return res.json(comments);
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          return res.json({error: `Could not get comments on post ID ${postId}`});
        });
```

in the frontend, I set the thread comment count be 0, so the query starts again at 0, hence it gets the same data. The fields that I know are to be different is commentId (the doc id) or the time posted for now. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  The code here shows many queries, not just one, so it's hard to tell what you're referring to.  Please trim this example down to one query, and describe the specific behavior of that one query that's not working the way you want.

Comment: Okay, i trimmed everything and added a comment in the code of the exact query that's giving me trouble. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the last document snapshot of the previous page to the next page's cursor clause as the starting point.

In you Cloud Function, instead of `startAfter` being a `threadCommentCount` value, you could pass the docId of the last document, then retrieve its document snapshot to pass to the `.startAfter()` method.

Here is an [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor) of this in the docs

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It sparked in idea in my head that wasn't there before lol. I'm just gonna pass in the commentId to the backend and get the snapshot from there. Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Jose V, But it will add extra read count just to get the snapshot for query purpose. Is there any better way than this?